# How to use DynamoDB batchGet command

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I created a "Movie" DynamoDB table from AWS DynamoDB tutorial posted at

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Js.01.html

with the attribute below:

```
    var tableAttrs = {
        TableName : "Movies",
        KeySchema: [
            { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},
            { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions: [
            { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
            { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        }
    };
```

Now I want to use the `batchGet` command:

```
var params = {
  "RequestItems" : {
      "Movies": {
        "Keys" : [
          {year : { "N" : "1000" } },
          {year : { "N" : "1001" } }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

And running it with:

```
let db = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10' })

let result = db.batchGet(params).promise();
```

But I am getting the error:

```
ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Why does the provided `year` as a key element does not match the schema? How to avoid this error and make it work?

Below is the screenshot showing the table keys:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) : From the Docs

> The BatchGetItem operation returns the attributes of one or more items
> from one or more tables. You identify requested items by primary key.

We must specify entire primary key i.e combination of partition key and sort key. Same with GetItem too.

**Batch Get:**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
documentClient.batchGet(
  {
    RequestItems: {
      Movies: {
        Keys: [
          { year: 1000, title: "one" },
          { year: 1000, title: "two" },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  function (err, data) {
    console.log("err", err, "data", JSON.stringify(data));
  }
);
```

To get by records only by Partition Key, we can use query.

**Query**:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
documentClient.query(
  {
    TableName: "Movies",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#year = :yearValue ",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":yearValue": 1000,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#year": "year",
    },
  },
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else
      console.log("dynamodb query succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  }
);
```